# Shift array to the left

Tags: java, arrays, int

so I'm trying to shift an array to the left, eg, if the original array was '1,2,3,4', the transformed one would become '2,3,4,1', this is what i have so far and i keep getting an missing return statement error, how would i go about fixing it?

```
public int shift  ( int [] d){

    for(int from =1; from <= d.length-1; from++)
        d[from-1]= d[from];

       System.out.println ("d[from]"+",d[0]");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's because you're missing a return statement.

Comment: "i keep getting an missing return statement error" because you're not returning anything even though your method says it returns an `int`.

Comment: Also, you need to keep the initial value of `d[0]`, so you can assign it to the last element of the final array. And your `println` probably won't print what you intend.

Comment: Why don't use [Collections Rotate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int))?

Comment: @juanlumn Because it's a primitive array.

Comment: This is rather a misnomer: it's not shifting but rotating the array. Rotating would wrap round like what you're describing. Shifting would be filling the bits with something else (in this case probably 0 but I'm very very tired, I am thinking of both right and left shift not to mention unsigned and signed ints and in C - and not going to think any further on it).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void shift(int[] arr, int offs) {
    // e.g. arr = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9; offs = 3
    offs %= arr.length;
    offs = offs < 0 ? arr.length + offs : offs;

    if (offs > 0) {
        // reverse whole array (arr = 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
        for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
            swap(arr, i, j);
        // reverse left part (arr = 7,8,9,6,5,4,3,2,1)
        for (int i = 0, j = offs - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
            swap(arr, i, j);
        // reverse right part (arr = 7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6)
        for (int i = offs, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
            swap(arr, i, j);
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your logic is right but you just need some modify in your code.**

```
int data[]={1,2,3,4};

shift(data); 

//print out Shifted Array
for(int n : data){
    System.out.println(n);
}

   public void shift(int[] d){
        int f=d[0]; // Store first index

        int from=1;
        for(;from<d.length;from++){
            d[from-1]=d[from];
        }       

        d[from-1]=f; //set first index to the last index 
    }
```

> You don't need to return any data because java pass the reference of
>   the object not value.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Collections.rotate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int)):

```
public List<Integer> shift(int [] d) {
  List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  for (int index = 0; index < d.length; index++) {
    intList.add(d[index]);
  }

  Collections.rotate(intList, -1);
  return intList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is in PHP to shift the array to left based on the given transformation number.

```
 <?php
    $a = [2,3,4,5,6];
    $k1 = 2;
    $k2 = 10;

    function leftshift($ar, $n , $k){
        $mod = $k % $n;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            echo ($ar[($mod +  $i) % $n]) , " "; 
            echo "\n";
        }
    }

    $n = count($a);
    leftshift($a,$n,$k1);
    leftshift($a,$n,$k2); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int shift (int[] d) {

    for(int from =1; from <= d.length-1; from++)
        d[from-1]= d[from];

    System.out.println ("d[from]"+",d[0]");
    return d.length=0?0:d[0];
}
```

Note that an array maybe of size zero, and you may get "index out of bounds  exception".

Comment: hi do u mind explaining this part? d.length=0?0:d[0]